# How to add a parameter that is from the state to an async action in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need to pass and params to async action. The param is searchField value which has a separate action and reducer. I need to pass the param because it is a part of the URL for the fetch call I am doing. Here is the code from the actions, reduce and App.js files:

Actions.js:

```
export const setSearchField = text => {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
    payload: text
  };
};

export const requestMeal = () => dispatch => {
  const url = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=asd`
  dispatch({ type: REQUEST_MEAL_PENDING });
  fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(url);
      dispatch({ type: REQUEST_MEAL_SUCCESS, payload: data.meals });
    })
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: REQUEST_MEAL_FAILED, payload: err }));
};
```

Reducers.js :

```
const initalStateSearch = {
  searchField: ""
};

export const searchMeals = (state = initalStateSearch, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { searchField: action.payload });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
/////////

// reducer and initia; state for requestMeal action

const initalStateRequestMeal = {
  isPending: false,
  meals: [],
  error: ""
};

export const requestMeal = (state = initalStateRequestMeal, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_MEAL_PENDING:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isPending: true });
    case REQUEST_MEAL_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isPending: false,
        meals: action.payload
      });
    case REQUEST_MEAL_FAILED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isPending: false,
        error: action.error
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

App.js

```
const mapStateToPros = state => {
  return {
    searchField: state.searchMeals.searchField,
    meals: state.requestMeal.meals,
    isPending: state.requestRandomMeal.isPending,
    error: state.requestRandomMeal.error,
    meal: state.requestViewMeal.meal
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSearchChange: event => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value)),
    onRequestMeal: () => dispatch(requestMeal()),
    onRequestRandomMeal: () => dispatch(requestRandomMeal()),
    onRequestViewMeal: event =>
      dispatch(requestViewMeal(event.target.getAttribute("data-id")))
  };
};
```

I need to pass to the `onRequestMeal()` parameters `searchField` that comes in the state from the other action `onSearchChange()`.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the files in post instead of pastebin

Comment: you need to use redux-thunk to handle async actions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using redux saga or not, but nevertheless, you should be able to dispatch the value of the input along with the action.
You should've posted your code, not pastebin :)
So your action creator would look something like

`export const searchRequest = (term) => ({
  type: SEARCH_REQUEST_START,
  term,
});`

provided that you have a `SEARCH_REQUEST_START` action, of course :)

and then from your component you can just dispatch something like

`const search = (event) => {
    dispatch(searchRequest(event.target.value));
  };`

and regardless of whether you're using saga or not, you should have the input value available in your get function, or reducer, via `action`

Hope this helps. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)